# Accurate Human Skull Model for Educational Purpose

Tags: human-anatomy

I want to buy a model of Human skull for education purpose. However, I really want a very accurate model and at a decent price. I got the info that many of the available skulls in the market are not accurate.  Can anyone suggest me one?

Also I want to know is there any regulatory body that certifies such
educational models regarding the accuracy etc.? If not then what is the way I can ensure that I am buying an accurate (or most accurate) model.

Comment: Which location are you enquiring for?

Comment: Product recommendation are often seen as not strong questions across the network, however the second part of your question is very interesting

Comment: Maybe you can find and print a 3d model near your location?

Comment: I am unable to understand why is location important, when I can order online

Comment: @gpuguy this is very difficult to answer without knowing: what models you have been told are inaccurate, how/why they are insufficiently accurate, what you need the model for, how accurate you need the model to be, what features you need to be accurate... There is never going to be the perfect skull model because everyone's skull is different and there is considerable natural variation in skull morphology, illustrative examples: http://www.understandingrace.org/images/482x270/science/early_class.jpg and http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/bigphotos/images/070718-african-origin_big.jpg

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about product recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to ensure you're getting an accurate skull, near as I can tell, is striking the "model" part of your question, and go straight for a *real* skull.

A cursory search revealed, for instance, [Skulls Unlimited International](http://www.skullsunlimited.com/o/82/natural-bone-human-skulls.htm), [The Bone Room](https://www.boneroom.com/welcome.aspx?c=1857&n=RealHumanSkulls), and [The Evolution Store](http://theevolutionstore.com/store/real-human-skulls/) although other providers probably exist as well.

A regulatory board for model skulls probably doesn't exist, given the apparent ease with which real skulls can be obtained and kept.

Comment: Yuck but +1 for new info